# I want to use fog to show that it is heated

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

[image]

I want to create a fog like a Gif.

I tried to make it with volume node by referring to the Tutorial, but I am not satisfied with it.
[image]

Would it be better to use a simulation?

If you know a better way, please let me know.

---

Reffer Tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoggY_6v5qQ&t=229s&ab_channel=RyanKingArt
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create this node setup: *Noise Texture > ColorRamp > Emission > Volume* input of the *Material Output*. To animate it, keyframe the position of the *ColorRamp* needles, the *W* factor of the *Noise Texture* (set to 4D), etc...:

[image]

If you use Eevee it will need a bit more tweakings: In the *Render* panel, under *Volumetrics*, lower the *Tile Size* down to 2 and increase the *Samples* to have a better resolution (and also the *Distribution* value if you can't see the result in the camera).

If you don't want your fog to emit any light, use a *Shader > Volume Scatter* instead (or a *Principled Volume*) and plug the *ColorRamp* into its *Density* input:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for plite reply!
I tried your way! 
Image : https://ibb.co/fNzZgQ4

but I would like to ask you more 2 questions,
1.I want to prevent fog from penetrating through it. (I want the fog to be invisible where there is a metal box in the foreground.)

2. The color is a little light, perhaps due to the light, so we want to make it darker (we have selected a darker color in node's color ramp).

I am sorry for the repetitiveness of this question, but I would appreciate your response.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean, penetrating through what? The fog will stay within the shape that you'll give to your object. For the color, please see my edit

Comment: I would like to hide the fog about the circled area of the image.
In the first Gif I posted, you can't see the fog in the area that is covered with the box. I want to do the same.

Comment: I have added a blendfull and would appreciate it if you could tell me what is wrong.

Comment: @Hana It looks like it has to do with the Distribution value in Render panel > Volumetrics, try to lower it down

Comment: So true!
Thank you so much for all your kind words!

Comment: Note that in Eevee by default you can only use cuboids for volumetric, unless you use Volume Empty

Comment: Thank you so much again!
I tweaked the numbers after that and got an expression I was happy with! Thank you very much

Comment: @Hana Glad I could help  ;)